# Building Package fails due to test coverage on salesforce

Tags: salesforce

my package contains class A for which I have written all tests but still while uploading it says I need to cover tests for all classes and fails. Help!

Comment: What is the code coverage % it tells you? How many classes and triggers do you have? Do all these have unit tests?

Comment: Only one class, it shows 75% for that class and total 20%

Comment: So Salesforce thinks that you have other code, maybe triggers, that needs to be covered too.

Comment: If he isn't uploading other files there is no worry about their coverage. I like the idea with separate test file.

Answer (score 3):

Are the tests embedded in the class definition or stored in a separate file?

If they are stored in a separate file ensure that this file is also included in the package.